# Adding NSG to Log Analytics Workspace fails

Tags: azure-log-analytics

Trying to add a Network Security Group to a Log Analytics Workspace, getting the following error. This used to work in version 5.0.0 but no longer works with 5.0.1.

```
Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $NsgFrontendSubnet.Id -WorkspaceId $LogAnalyticsWorkspace.ResourceId -Enabled $true -Categories 'NetworkSecurityGroupEvent','NetworkSecurityGroupRuleCounter'
```

> Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting : Exception type: ErrorResponseException,
>   Message: The diagnostic setting 'service' doesn't exist., Code: ResourceNotFound, Status code:NotFound, Reason
>   phrase: Not Found At PAT0056-NetworkSecurityGroupNew:764 char:764
>   +
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmDiagnosticSetting], PSInvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.Diagnostics.SetAzureRmDiagnosticSettingCommand

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug reported on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6833

Only way to get around it is to revert to AzureRm.Insights 5.0.0